# Grails Apache Camel Plugin runtime dependency "runtime 'org.apache.camel:camel-mail:2.9.0'" causing application to stop

Tags: grails, apache-camel, grails-plugin

I have recently upgraded my Grails application to version 2.3.5 from 2.2.3

But after that my application is not statrting at all, after searching and debugging the application and plugins by adding all the plugins in a new application. The application runs only when i remove the below dependency from BuildConfig.groovy.

Apache Camel Plugin runtime dependency for Receiving emails from GMail

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.apache.camel:camel-mail:2.9.0'
}
```

causing application to stop by throwing below Exception

Please help me in resolving the issue, I have also tried with Apache Camel Plugin latest version 1.2.9 but no luck so far.

```
Error |
2014-02-05 12:10:05,196 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->> 3357 | <init>                    in java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   3343 | asList                    in java.util.Arrays
|    238 | getDeclaredFields . . . . in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator
|     47 | getDeclaredFields         in     ''
|    359 | findFieldProperties . . . in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl
|    290 | getProperties             in     ''
|    165 | getProperties . . . . . . in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl
|    232 | getClassInfo              in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder
|     89 | getClassInfo . . . . . .  in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder
|     70 | getClassInfo              in     ''
|    198 | getClassInfo . . . . . .  in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder
|     84 | getClassInfo              in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder
|     70 | getClassInfo . . . . . .  in     ''
|    304 | getTypeInfo               in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder
|    319 | getTypeInfo . . . . . . . in     ''
|    430 | getTypeInfoSet            in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
|    277 | <init> . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|   1100 | build                     in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder
|    143 | createContext . . . . . . in com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
|    110 | createContext             in     ''
|    191 | createContext . . . . . . in     ''
|    128 | newInstance               in javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder
|    290 | find . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    372 | newInstance               in javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
|    337 | newInstance . . . . . . . in     ''
|    188 | createJaxbContext         in org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler
|    175 | getJaxbContext . . . . .  in     ''
|    303 | doParse                   in org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser
|    131 | invokeMethod . . . . . .  in grails.spring.DynamicElementReader
|     61 | doCall                    in RoutingGrailsPlugin$_closure1
|    756 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    584 | beans                     in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod . . . . . .  in     ''
|    303 | innerRun                  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    138 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|    886 | runTask                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
^    662 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: @tim_yates I am also facing the same issue will upgrading from 2.2.4 to 2.3.4. We are using camel and routing plugin in our project and error log is [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory
Message:org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory
   Line | Method
->> 2531 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   2002 | getDeclaredMethod         in     ''